# JqGrid custom function editoptions

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with a column which have a custom editoptions.

```
      editable: true,
      edittype: "custom",
      editoptions: { custom_element: itemFirstPaidElem, custom_value: itemFirstPaidValue
```

Here are the two custom function:

```
function itemFirstPaidElem(value, options) {
    var el = "<label>" + value + "</label><a style='margin-left:10px' href='#' class='ItemFirstPaidPickValue' value='" + value + "'><img src='" + path + "/Content/Images/calendar_edit.png'/></a>";
    return el;
}

function itemFirstPaidValue(elem, operation, value) {
    if (operation === 'get') {
        var val = $(elem).text();
        return val;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the content of the label when the user has finished the line edit.
The thing is that the object $(elem).text(); is always undefined.

I had a look in chrome developer tool and what I see is that the value I need are contain in the prevObject.

[image]

I've tried to call $(elem).prevObject.text() but it didn't work, I'm not really sure of what it is. 
Can somebody help me on that point.

Thanks in advancce